# Cannot remove "Use Windows Hello with your account" message during OOBE

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, intune, windows-hello

I've done some tests about Windows 11 laptops & Azure AD enduser experience. I've created a completely new tenant for this purpose. I haven't added any security/identity licenses to it, and I haven't made any security settings enabled. However, after joining the laptop to AAD and successfully logging in, I encountered a screen that said, "Use Windows Hello with your account," and "Your organization requires you to set up your work or school account with Windows Hello face, fingerprint, or PIN," which is a big lie!

Here are the settings I've applied:

Conditional Access \ Policies
There are no policies.

Conditional Access \ Classic policies
There are no policies.

endpoint.microsoft.com \ Home \ Devices \ Windows \ Windows Enrollment \ Windows Hello for Business \ Configure Windows Hello For Business: Disabled

endpoint.microsoft.com \ Home \ Endpoint security \ Account protection \ Create policy: Account protection (Preview) \ Block Windows Hello for Business: Enabled, Assigned for all users

endpoint.microsoft.com \ Home \ Devices \ Configuration profiles \ Profile: myprofile \ Configuration settings \ Configure Windows Hello For Business: Use Passport For Work
False

Azure Active Directory\Security \Authentication methods \ Registration campaign (Because there is mention about Microsoft Authenticator) State: Disabled

Azure Active Directory \ Properties \ Security defaults
Disabled

Microsoft Entra Admin Center\ Protection \ Identity Protection \ Multifactor authentication registration policy \ Controls: Require Azure AD multifactor authentication registration: Users Excluded \ Policy enforcement: Disabled

Despite turning off many of the settings "just in case" and even creating a demo Intune account to perform some of these settings (which is completely unacceptable!), I couldn't get rid of the Windows Hello enforcement during the initial sign-in, even after creating a new user.

In my research on this issue, I've come to the conclusion that once these settings are applied on a device, even if you disable the policy, it remains in effect. Is there a different solution that can be applied?
Note: Windows 11 is Enterprise edition without any modification.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after assigning licenses on Intune, it seems the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for documenting what you found out in an answerm. [You should now '**accept**' your answer so others know your question is solved](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @gregg they may have to wait a day or two to be able to accept their own answer. https://superuser.com/help/self-answer "You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so."